# MS Access Looping a union query through all columns?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, union

Is it possible to simplify the following into a loop?

```
SELECT ID as ColHead, "Field1" AS RowHead, Field1 AS TheVal
FROM `master`
UNION
SELECT ID, "Field2",Field2
FROM `master`
UNION
SELECT ID, "Field3",Field3
FROM `master`
UNION
...
SELECT ID, "Field90",Field90
FROM `master`
```

There are 90 fields. Before I start writing this by hand, is there a way to simplify the process?

Comment: I think that instead of constructing a UNION query of this type, you can use a CROSSTAB query. Just use a wizard, it is very easy.

Comment: It looks to me like he is trying to undo a crosstab type query.  Yes VBA with a SQL string built in a loop is the way to go.  If the fields are actually numbered as you show in the example it's pretty easy, otherwise if 100% of the fields past ID are going to be used it's also easy otherwise you may want to build a single column table just to hold the names of the fields you want to unwind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you build that massive `UNION` query, consider `UNION ALL` instead.

`UNION ALL` will return *all* rows from each `SELECT` piece, including duplicate rows.  With just `UNION`, the db engine returns only distinct rows.  However ensuring distinct rows imposes a greater burden on the engine.

Use `UNION` if you require only distinct rows.  Use `UNION ALL` if you can accept duplicate rows.  Also use `UNION ALL` when the candidate rows can not include duplicates to begin with.

If that `ID` field is the `master` primary key, or if you have another unique constraint (index) on `ID`, the candidate rows will already be unique.  If that is your situation, use `UNION ALL` to make that big query easier on the db engine.

Actually I'm apprehensive about trying to `UNION` (or `UNION ALL`) 89 `SELECTs`.  I've never attempted such a huge SQL statement.  If you want to try, I'll offer another approach.

I created a VBA function to create the SQL statement.  It reads the field names from the `TableDef` and loops through those names to add a `SELECT` piece for each field name.

Here is an Immediate window session where I tested the function in Access 2007.  My `master` table includes only 4 fields: `ID`; `fld1`; `fld2`; and `fld3`.

```vba
? BuildUnionStatement
SELECT ID as ColHead, 'fld1' AS RowHead, [fld1] AS TheVal
FROM [master]
UNION ALL
SELECT ID as ColHead, 'fld2' AS RowHead, [fld2] AS TheVal
FROM [master]
UNION ALL
SELECT ID as ColHead, 'fld3' AS RowHead, [fld3] AS TheVal
FROM [master]
```

I don't know what you intend to do with the query after you create it.  But a function to create the SQL offers flexibility.  You could use the function's output to open a recordset, save it as a `QueryDef`, for the record source of a form or report, etc.

```vb
Public Function BuildUnionStatement() As String
    Const cstrTable As String = "master"
    Dim db As DAO.database
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strSql As String

    'strPattern = vbCrLf & "UNION" & vbCrLf & 
    strPattern = vbCrLf & "UNION ALL" & vbCrLf & _
        "SELECT ID as ColHead, " & _
        "'FLDNAME' AS RowHead, " & _
        "[FLDNAME] AS TheVal" & vbCrLf & _
        "FROM [" & cstrTable & "]"

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set tdf = db.TableDefs(cstrTable)
    For Each fld In tdf.Fields
        If fld.Name <> "ID" Then
            strSql = strSql & Replace(strPattern, _
                "FLDNAME", fld.Name)
        End If
    Next

    Set fld = Nothing
    Set tdf = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

    'BuildUnionStatement = Mid(strSql, 10) ' UNION
    BuildUnionStatement = Mid(strSql, 14) ' UNION ALL
End Function
```

After you save that function in a module, open the Immediate window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>).  To execute the function, type this and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
? BuildUnionStatement
```

Copy the text it returns, create a new query and switch to SQL View, then paste in the copied text.

Since that gave you too much text to copy from the Immediate window, create a new query --- any query will work.  Then assign the function's output to the query's SQL property.  Do this in the Immediate window ...

```
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("YourQueryNameHere").SQL = BuildUnionStatement
```

Comment: Hey man thanks for looking at this question. I have a question though, where do you put the call to run the function? Putting it in the SQL view throws up errors. Is it supposed to be in a macro?

Comment: I ran the function from the Immediate window; you could copy the text and paste it somewhere.  Where do you want to use it?

Comment: Well i pasted the function to a module. but how do I call it in a query?

Comment: Create a query and use the output from the function as the query's SQL.  I added a note to the answer.

Comment: Oh alright gotcha thanks. That works beautifully. Although its too many lines for the immediate window to display. I guess i can fill in the rest manually. Thanks!

Comment: OK, I should have seen that coming.  See the latest note.

Comment: Ok. I keep getting  'The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object ".' when i try to go from sql view to datasheet view

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29205/discussion-between-hansup-and-gta0004)